# No Runnable Methods and Test Class Should Have Exactly One Public Constructor Exception

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit

I can't seem to shake this error. The Eclipse Runner appears to find the @Test annotations however the BlockJUnit4ClassRunner validateConstructor and validateInstanceMethods can't see the @Test annotations.

I have read In this case, Test.class have been loaded with the system ClassLoader (i.e. the one that loaded JUnitCore), therefore technically none of the test methods will have been annotated with that annotation.

Solution is to load JUnitCore in the same ClassLoader as the tests themselves.

I've tried updating the JUnitCore in the same ClassLoader however missed the exact configuration. I have also tried an external runner along with try/catch to consume the error.. Nothing appears to work.

How would I...

1. Junit Runner to identify the class,
   or
2. Possibly Ignore this error in a try/catch 
   or
3. Implement the correct structure for the ClassLoader solution?

I've attached a copy of code in git repository reference. bhhc.java throws the exception upon execution.

Supported Data:

SRC: https://github.com/agolem2/MavenJunit/blob/master/src/Test/bhhc.java

ERROR:

Google
Completed Test Case bhhc Date:  2017-09-26 08_57_17.318
Test run was NOT successful:

```
No runnable methods - Trace: java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4Cl
assRunner.java:191)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUni
t4ClassRunner.java:128)


Test class should have exactly one public constructor - Trace: 
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public constructor
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateOnlyOneConstructor(BlockJUnit
4ClassRunner.java:158)
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassR
unner.java:147)
```

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525521

Comment: Did you ever solve this yourself?